# How can I make a Dynamic Inbound Endpoint in Mule?

Tags: esb, mule

Is there any way to set Inbound Endpoint attributes based on data in an event?

This is my scenario: 
I receive messages from a JMS queue containing a path as payload, then I want to use a File Inbound Endpoint to read from the path that came in the message and process the resulting files. 
I know only outbound endpoints are supposed to be dynamic.

Any workaround to solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing else works, inject the path to a custom component and read the file in that component. Then you can return the file or what ever you want as a payload.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't want to do that way, but at the end I did as you said. The main drawback for me is that Mule uses a Request operation. Request is not as flexible as Receiving and you can't override the Request component in the endpoint.

Comment: If anyone else want to know more about this go to this [post](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/dynamic-requesting-with-mule-esb/)

Answer (score 0):

Answering this even though the OP is old as t still comes up in searches.   A reasonable solution for this is to use the Mule Requester Module community component which can be added from exchange.  The MRM can takes a resource, which can be of any resource type such as a file on a File directory, FTP path, SFTP, or a JMS Queue entry, etc.  The resource is define full path, like file:///filepath/somefilename, so the name and path is set dynamically, not statically as with a file inbound endpoint, so in this case could be built from information received from the JMS queue.